# Should I be doing checks on data that I'm supposed to be able to trust?

Tags: design

I am working on the frontend of a product, and it is now broken due to bad data from the backend.

This can be caught internally before it gets anywhere close to production, but we end up fiddling with our fingers as the backend is being fixed. (Hence why I'm here...)

I have some hackish fix that does a sanity check, in this particular instance, on the data being received; does this imply I have to do a check for *all* data?

Answer (score 8):

Honestly, how much do you trust the data from the backend after the actual experience? I guess not 100%, so adding some additional checks might be worth it to catch some potential bugs.

However, we do not know your product, we do not know what happens when your frontend gets broken, and what financial risk is at stake when your users see the kind of error message your product shows now with "bad data". We also do not know if your product becomes totally unusable, or if only a minor feature of your product does not work. We also do not know if sanitizing "all data" means only a few hours of additional work, or a three months delay in delivery. But **these are the factors you have to consider** when asking yourself "shall I add only a few checks" or "shall I sanitize all input data like hell".

Comment: Sanitizing all the data I receive from backend is infeasible, as mentioned by @steve-chamaillard below. As I mentioned, I can add a check just for this 1 piece of data so that we don't get a fatal error, we'd be missing some minor functionality, and the site would work. But if we had to do this everytime we get bad data, it adds up and so we would either need to validate data formats (which is hard in this case because the backend does not have a consistent data format...) for all requests and fail gracefully if it doesn't validate, or keeping adding checks here and there and have ugly code...

Comment: @Populus: I have never encountered a situation where it was totally infeasible to check the input data in a minimal way so the program does not fully break, at least by adding some try/catch blocks and showing or logging an error message telling which piece of the input data was wrong when you cannot parse it in a meaningful way. Of course, when you wrote some ten thousand lines of code over some weeks or months without doing any checks so far, then you might have a problem now. However, the earlier you start solving that problem, the earlier you will get it solved.

Comment: We have code that does checks here and there, usually because the backend does not return consistent response formats (i.e. json keys may or may not exist depending on the object being returned, and the entire response may contain objects that don't all have the same keys...), but this is the first time where the data being returned was outright incorrect: facet data being returned is incorrect, we do some logic in the frontend that assumes that the facet associated with an object exists, this is where it breaks. How should I handle this case? Does this mean we have to handle it everywhere?

Comment: @Populus: sorry, but I fear this cannot be answered here in a general way - one needs to know your system, the components, the requirements, the environment, and the problems you have in detail to find an appropriate solution. Your question sounds like you hope there is a "silver bullet" to solve your problems - there is not, and that is what I am trying to tell you.

Comment: I know there won't be a silver bullet, I'm wondering if I should handle every break of contract by the backend case-by-case, or assume anything on the backend may incorrect... The latter choice creates a lot of overhead, for an internal backend that we should really have trust in. The former makes our frontend code more fragile, because we have to hardcode assumptions in. So I am wondering other people have more insight on the matter, or maybe have alternative solutions

Answer (score 2):

Only about functionality, not security:

Only trust data from the backend when it's the same system/solution. So what that means:

If you have an application in something like Meteor / Nodejs with Angular or a MS solution with both client and server in one application you could trust it.

That is because it's one solution and it will be deployed and tested as a whole. It uses the same delivery pipeline. In this case if something goes wrong your integration / end-to-end tests are wrong. You fix them and you are stable again.

When the backend is a different application (let's say a separate PHP app) which can even be from a different supplier / team treat it as an external source. Validate as much of the data as possible. Why: Because that backend can be changed and they might not notify you. So your software may do wrong things based on their error and changes.

Comment: This! And I might add that you should not trust a backend which accepts data from other sources than your own application. At least when communicating without a proper schema or a very relaxed one.

Answer (score 0):

Data should be validated at the source, and it would be nice if a routine only got valid data.  In the real world though that is seldom the case.  Even for reliable sources, data is seldom 100% as pure as falling snow.  Doc hits some key points.  I will just add a question to reinforce:  How bad is it if the data is not clean?  What are the consequences?  The worse the results can be of processing invalid data, the more imperative it is that data be sanitized before processing no matter how well you trust the source.  As consequences of processing bad data go down, the more you can accept data without validation for sources judged reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I generally trust data from the back-end and distrust data from the front-end.  If the back-end is returning bad data, it likely got there from a broken front-end.  If you can't trust your back-ends, you are unlikely to be able to provide reliable results.

Data coming from systems should in general be validated.  How detailed this validation is depends on the type of data.  Some of the validations I use include:

- type: This may be sufficient for many values.
- range: Often applies to numeric values.
- length: Often applies to strings.
- valid values: Less common.
- cross-field checks: eg. country = US, state = Yukon is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are referring to a typical client-sever architecture based application. Its always a good idea to implement sanity checks or input validation on BOTH sides of the application (client side and server side). This will ensure that you have an additional layer of sanity checks at each side of the application.

Now in the case of your example if you believe that the backend data is somehow wrong and that you have to always wait for a fix in order to return the front-end to a good working state; then it would be a better idea to put some of the development efforts in producing helpful error states within the application instead of it "just being broken" or Hacky fixes. By producing a helpful error state you can perform further root causes analysis.

What I mean by helpful error states here is basically a model to capture the root cause of the issue but displaying a relevant contextual message to the user at the front-end. For example When its broken and its a customer looking at the screen then "*Say its Temporarily Unavailable, Please try again in X hours...*" or something, but when a developer/ looks at it make sure that it has enough relevant error details so that they can investigate the issue or follow up with the right individuals.

Answer (score -2):

Well, checking data received in the front end may be a good thing to provide the user with quick feedback if there's an error.

Still, this is most often than not overkill and it could be dangerous, if specs change and the validation changes with it, you might check data in the front end in some ways and the back end in other ways, which will create inconsistencies.

I don't agree with

> the backend team broke the frontend because of some bad data being returned to us

though, they broke the backend there. The front end shouldn't be impacted at all even if the data is bad, since it's only a layer of presentation of datas.

Comment: I agree that frontend should not be impacted, and I should've worded that statement better "our frontend broke as a result of bad data received from the backend". So my question is still: do I need to pre-empt all potential bad data scenarios? Or deal with them as they arrive?

Comment: Your second paragraph doesn't make much sense to me. If the specification changes the validation rules and you are still using the old validation rules, then there is simply a bug in your code. It's not the fact that you use *different validation rules* which is the problem, but the bug itself.

Comment: Also, since when presentation layer is not impacted by the data? In order to present something, you should know the schema; if the data doesn't match the schema, the presentation layer would be possibly unable to present it.

Comment: My second paragraph was about the fact that he seems to have problems working in sync with the back end team. So obviously that would cause a bug, but no front end validation wouldn't ever have this bug caused, especially if the validations are redundant anyway.
Also the presentation layer *is not* impacted by the back end, the *data* is. The data should be shown thanks to this layer, this layer shouldn't be used by the data itself. If so, there's a problem in the lower layers (which is the case here).